# Código não exibe

Tags: php

estou fazendo uma página que puxa informação do BD:

```
<?php   
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") 
    or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados");      
    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($conexao,"mentoria"); 
    $campos = array(".", "-");      

    if(isset($_FILES['foto'])){ 
        $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['foto']['name'], -4));
        $novo_nome = md5(time()). $extensao;
        $diretorio = "imagem/";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);
    }

    $cpf = str_replace($campos,"",$_POST["inputCPF"]);

    $consulta_jovens = "SELECT jfoto,jnome,jfaixaetaria,jescolaridade,jhobby,jcomida,jmusica,jesporte,jtime,jcaracteristica,janimal,jlivro,jsonho, ((CASE WHEN jovem.jfaixaetaria = mentor.mfaixaetaria THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jescolaridade = mentor.mescolaridade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jhobby = mentor.mhobby THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcomida = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jmusica = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jesporte = mentor.mesporte THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jtime = mentor.mtime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcaracteristica = mentor.mcaracteristica THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.janimal = mentor.manimal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jlivro = mentor.mlivro THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jsonho = mentor.msonho THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS qtdCaracteristicasIguais FROM jovem INNER JOIN mentor ON jovem.jcidade = mentor.mcidade AND jovem.jestado = mentor.mestado WHERE mentor.mcidade = jovem.jcidade AND mentor.mestado   = jovem.jestado AND mentor.CPF ='$cpf' and jselecionado IS null ORDER BY qtdCaracteristicasIguais DESC LIMIT 2";

    $string_sql = "SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE CPF='$cpf'";      

    $result= mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql); 

    $resultadojovens = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta_jovens);

    $dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);            

    $nome = $dado['mnome'];     

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao)){ 


        echo "<p><h2>Olá, $nome! <br><br> Escolha o seu mentorando abaixo:</h2></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p></p>";}

?>

<form>
  <tr>
    <th>Foto</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Faixa Etária</th>
    <th>Escolaridade</th>
    <th>Hobby</th>
    <th>Comida</th>
    <th>Estilo Musical</th>
    <th>Esporte</th>
    <th>Time de Futebol</th>
    <th>Caracteristica</th>
    <th>Animal favorito</th>
    <th>Livro</th>
    <th>Sonho</th>
    <th>Ação</th> 
  </tr>
<?
while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){
?>
  <tr>
    <td><img style="width:70%" src=imagem/<?$aluno['jfoto']?>/></td> 
    <td><?$aluno['jnome']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jfaixaetaria']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jescolaridade']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jhobby']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jcomida']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jmusica']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jesporte']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jtime']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jcaracteristica']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['janimal']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jlivro']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jsonho']?></td>   
    <td><a href="selecao.php?id="<?$aluno['jCPF']?>>Selecionar</a></td> 
  </tr>
<?
}

?>
</form>
<html>
<head>
```

Porém ele não traz nenhuma informação

```
    <?
while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){
?>
  <tr>
    <td><img style="width:70%" src=imagem/<?$aluno['jfoto']?>/></td> 
    <td><?$aluno['jnome']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jfaixaetaria']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jescolaridade']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jhobby']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jcomida']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jmusica']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jesporte']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jtime']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jcaracteristica']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['janimal']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jlivro']?></td>
    <td><?$aluno['jsonho']?></td>   
    <td><a href="selecao.php?id="<?$aluno['jCPF']?>>Selecionar</a></td> 
  </tr>
<?
}

?>
```

Qual seria o problema?

Comment: Olá, Junior!

Eu não consigo colar o resultado aqui mas aparece tudo: array(28) { [0]=> string(36) "a2cd02477841b92a2c968634deab79a3.jpg" ["jfoto"]=> string(36) "a2cd02477841b92a2c968634deab79a3.jpg" [1]=> string(11) "gfgdfgfgdfg" ["jnome"]=> string(11) "gfgdfgfgdfg" [2]=> string(17) "Abaixo de 20 anos"

Answer (score 1):

Para "printar" as informações, você deve utilizar a função `echo`, como por exemplo:

```
<?php echo $variavel ?>
```

ou então

```
<?= $variavel ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Substitua:

`while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){`

por

`while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadojovens)){`

e

Substitua:

`<td><?$aluno['jnome']?></td>`

por

`<td><?php echo $aluno['jnome']; ?></td>`

Comment: Não seria <?php echo $aluno['jnome']; ?> o correto?

Comment: Depende da configuração da máquina dela, mesmo assim, irei alterar

Comment: não funcionou...

Comment: alterei a resposta, veja se resolve

Comment: Resolveu, porém ele aparece somente 1 registro, o "While" fica comentado...

Comment: explica melhor essa questão do while comentado

Comment: e aí, algum resultado? conseguiu resolver?